# Building a custom machine code from the ground up

Tags: machine-code

I have recently begun working with logic level design as an amateur hobbyist but have now found myself running up against software, where I am much less competent. I have completed designing a custom 4 bit CPU in Logisim loosely based on the paper "A Very Simple Microprocessor" by Etienne Sicard. Now that it does the very limited functions that I've built into it (addition, logical AND, OR, and XOR) without any more detectable bugs (crossing fingers) I am running into the problem of writing programs for it. Logisim has the functionality of importing a script of Hex numbers into a RAM or ROM module so I can write programs for it using my own microinstruction code, but where do I start? I'm quite literally at the most basic possible level of software design and don't really know where to go from here. Any good suggestions on resources for learning about this low level of programming or suggestions on what I should try from here? Thanks much in advance, I know this probably isn't the most directly applicable question ever asked on this forum.

Comment: Vote to close because too broad. You might be interested by http://www.nand2tetris.org/course.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the paper you mention. But if you have designed your own custom CPU, then if you want to write software for it, you have two choices: a) write it in machine code, or b) write your own assembler.

Obviously I'd go with b. This will require that you shift gear a bit and do some high-level programming. What you are aiming to write is an assembler program that runs on a PC, and converts some simple assembly language into your custom machine code. The assembler itself will be a high-level program and as such, I would recommend writing it in a high-level programming language that is good at both string manipulation and binary manipulation. I would recommend Python.

You basically want your assembler to be able to read in a text file like this:

```
    mov a, 7
foo:
    mov b, 20
    add a, b
    cmp a, b
    jg foo
```

(I just made this program up; it's nonsense.)

And convert each line of code into the binary pattern for that instruction, outputting a binary file (or perhaps a hex file, since you said your microcontroller can read in hex values). From there, you will be able to load the program up onto the CPU.

So, I suggest you:

1. Come up with (on paper) an assembly language that is a simple written representation for each of the opcodes your machine supports (you may have already done this),
2. Learn simple Python,
3. Write a Python script that reads one line at a time (`sys.stdin.readline()`), figures out which opcode it is and what values it takes, and outputs the corresponding machine code to stdout.
4. Write some assembly code in your assembly language that will run on your CPU.

Sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Very helpful but it's actually a step or two ahead of where I'm at. I'm sure this will be useful in the future but right now I'm really interested in just *what* to do rather than how to do it. Maybe there are examples of how to do logical or mathematical operations in an existing ISA that I could use to figure out what can be done in my machine-code. From there I could work out further improvements such as building an assembler or adding more operations. As you mentioned I have worked out my language (only 6 op-codes so far and one is NOOP) but am fishing for what to do with it. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this. Maybe I'm confused about where you're at. I was trying to advise on *what* to do rather than how. From the question, it seems like you have the machine working and you can import machine code, but you are stuck because you can't write larger programs because it's too hard to type in all the opcodes. That's why I suggested writing an assembler as the next logical step. Or do you mean you are looking for suggestions on what programs to write in your machine code? In which case I don't think that question is really appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar that you might find interesting. I also have created from scratch my own CPU design. It is an 8-bit multi-cycle RISC CPU based on Harvard architecture with variable length instructions.

I started in Logisim, then coded everything in Verilog, and I have synthesized it in an FPGA.

To answer your question, I have done a simple and rudimentary assembler that translates a program (instructions, ie. mnemonics + data) to the corresponding machine language that can then be loaded into the PROG memory. I've written it in shell script and I use awk, which is what I was confortable with.

I basically do two passes: first translate mnemonics to their corresponding opcode and translate data (operands) into hex, here I keep track of all the labels addresses. second pass will replace all labels with their corresponding address.
(labels and addresses are for jumps)

You can see all the project, including the assembler, documented here: https://github.com/adumont/hrm-cpu

Answer (score 0):

Because your instruction set is so small, and based on the thread from the mguica answer, I would say the next step is to continue and/or fully test your instruction set.  do you have flags?  do you have branch instructions.  For now just hand generate the machine code.  Flags are tricky, in particular the overflow (V) bit.  You have to examine carry in and carry out on the msbit adder to get it right.  Because the instruction set is small enough you can try the various combinations of back to back instructions and followed by or and followed by xor and followed by add, or followed by and or followed by xor, etc.  And mix in the branches.  back to flags, if the xor and or for example do not touch carry and overflow then make sure you see carry and overflow being a zero and not touched by logical instructions and carry and overflow being one and not touched, and also independently show carry and overflow are separate, one on one off, not touched by logical, etc.  make sure all the conditional branches only operate on that one condition, lead into the various conditional branches with flag bits that are ignored in both states insuring that the conditional branch ignores them.  Also verify that if the conditional branch is not supposed to modify them that it doesnt.   likewise if the condition doesnt cause a branch that the conditional flags are not touched...

I like to use randomization but it may be more work than you are after.  I like to independently develop a software simulator of the instruction set, which I find easier to use that the logic also sometimes easier to use in batch testing.  you can then randomize some short list of instructions, varying the instruction and the registers, naturally test the tester by hand computing some of the results, both state of registers after test complete and state of flag bits.  Then make that randomized list longer, at some point you can take a long instruction list and run it on the logic simulator and see if the logic comes up with the same register results and flag bits as the instruction set simulator, if they vary figure out why.  If the do not try another random sequence, and another.  Filling registers with prime numbers before starting the test is a very good idea.

back to individual instruction testing and flags go through all the corner cases 0xFFFF + 0x0000 0xFFFF+1, things like that places just to the either side of and right on operands and results that are one count away from where a flag changes at the point where the flag changes and just the other side of that.  for the logicals for example if they use the zero flag, then have various data patterns that test results that are on either side of and at zero 0x0000, 0xFFFF 0xFFFE 0x0001 0x0002, etc.  Probably a walking ones result as well 0x0001 result 0x0002, ox0004, etc.

hopefully I understood your question and have not pointed out the obvious or what you have already done thus far.